Powershell array of strings into single SQL column
I've this array of strings:
$qLastSS_T
2024-07-08 11:56:32
2024-08-08 12:56:32
2024-09-08 13:56:32
2024-10-08 13:56:32
2024-11-08 15:56:32
2024-12-08 16:56:32

and a SQL table like this:

Is it possible to insert the values of array in to the "LAST_SS_DATE" column in order to obtain a result like this:

I'm not familiar with T-SQL and when LAST_SS_DATE has N/D as value, I'm using this syntax for the insert:
$GESQueryIN = "INSERT INTO Monitoraggio.dbo.IMGs_BKP (DATE,SERVER,SIDE,DAY,SUCCESS,FAILURE_REASON,SS_EXIST,LAST_SS_DATE,LAST_SS_EXIPIRE) VALUES ('$qDT_RunBKP','$_','$qSide','$qDayOfBKP','$qSucces','$qFailRea','$qSS_Exist','$qLastSS_T','$qLastSS_E');"

and I run it with the Invoke-SqlCmd cmdlet

You can join the strings using Concat, but you need a return at the end of each string : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

'one','two','three' -join "\n"` maybe

Just a side note. T-SQL / SQL Server does not support any sort of array/list data types. So your only option in the database would be to store the datetime values as strings. Like a CSV, JSON, XML, etc. If you don't have control over the schema, and this is how it's handled there, I understand. But if you do have control...then I would highly recommend storing these values in another table and use some sort of lookup key back in Monitoraggio.dbo.IMGs_BKP. Storing the datetime values as a list of strings within SQL Server is not a good practice.

LAST_SS_DATE is defined how as a column? Seems weird to add more that one date time value into a single column as a string.
